# CSS: align border to the circle

Tags: css

I'm trying to align the border to the circle, to make it look like clipped there.

Here is an example:
http://jsfiddle.net/Beck/P63VY/1/

```
<div class="circle">
</div>
<div class="rounded"></div>

.circle {
    width:150px;
    height:150px;
    border-radius:82px;
    border:7px solid black;
}
.rounded {
    position: absolute;
    left: 22px;
    top: 23px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    border-radius: 62px/66px 0px 0px 0px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
}
```

Is there a way to actually clip that top left corner?

Thanks.

Comment: make the radius same?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
.circle {
    width:150px;
    height:150px;
    border-radius:82px;
    border:7px solid black;
}
.rounded {
    position: absolute;
    left: 18px;
    top: 15px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    border-radius:72.5px;
    width: 145px;
    height: 145px;
}
</style>

<div class="circle">
<div class="rounded"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: i ve just provide solution let him talk ... will work foreword if any issue

Comment: no no, you just created two circles, i want that div to just stick to the circle and pick it's rounded form only in it's top left corner. The rest part of the red div should be the same as it is, as it will contain text.

Comment: i am not getting you can u upload image by making it in paint , a rough image

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Beck/P63VY/17/ i just need the corner of the red div to fit the circle as if it's the part of the circle.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/P63VY/7/ here how it should look, but not overflowed on the right.)

Answer (score 0):

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/P63VY/7/)

The way I did it is:

1. Place `<div class="rounded"></div>` inside the `<div class="circle">`
2. If you want to keep the `position: absolute` in `.rounded`, add `position: relative` to the parent `.circle`
3. Add `overflow: hidden` to the parent, so the child gets clipped.
4. Remove all `border-radius` from the child `.rounded` since it's no longer needed.

### HTML

```
<div class="circle">
    <div class="rounded"></div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.circle {
    width:150px;
    height:150px;
    border-radius:82px;
    border:7px solid black;

    /* These were added: */
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
}
.rounded {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
}
```

Comment: Overflow is not an option here. But i was thinking about it, maybe have to reconsinder the whole design.)

Comment: Oh remembered, it's not an option, because right side should be not overflowed and continue through the circle.

Comment: I was playing around with the overflows, and here's what I've come up with: http://jsfiddle.net/P63VY/66/ Does it at least *look* like something you wanted to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Make the radius the same for both classes and make the height of `.rounded` to half the height of `.circle`. I also have changed the `left` and `top` values to align it.

**HTML**

```
<div class="circle"></div>
<div class="rounded"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.circle {
    width:150px;
    height:150px;
    border-radius:82px;
    border:7px solid black;
}
.rounded {
    position: absolute;
    left: 12px;
    top: 12px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    border-radius: 82px 0px 0px 0px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 75px;
}
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Xs2Mr/.

Hope this helps!

Comment: But you moved the div itself to make it easier for yourself. What if the div has to be somewhere in the middle? The `border-radius` can't accommodate for a part of an arc.

Comment: well yeah, but i don't need red div to reach the top of the circle, it's just need to be as a ribbon, crossing almost the middle of the circle.

Comment: Guess there should be additional modifications applied to the bottom left corner as well, to make it fit the circle.

Comment: Yes, but it's not completely fit the circle, see the border is still not reaching the circle border at the top and bottom.

Comment: It's reaching the top of the circle. That's not what I was planning to do. It should not reach the top of the circle.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/P63VY/7/ here how it should look, but not overflowed on the right.)

Comment: @Somebody Ahhh I see what you mean, that's quite tricky - this may be close enough? Just a pixel or two out in the top left.... http://jsfiddle.net/zQyDj/

Answer (score 0):

I think Kai did it correctly, but in case you don't want it to touch the top of the circle, here is the best I could do with your fixed height of the red box.

http://jsfiddle.net/P63VY/18/

```
.circle {
    width:150px;
    height:150px;
    border-radius:82px;
    border:7px solid black;
}
.rounded {
    position: absolute;
    left: 20px;
    top: 23px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    border-radius: 150px / 160px 0px 0px 0px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
}
```

Comment: Yes, i get the same result.) It seems it's impossible to do it. Border-radius is not so flexible as it seems.

Answer (score 0):

try if any issue comment it

```
<style>

.circle {
   border: 7px solid black;
    border-radius: 82px 82px 82px 82px;
    height: 150px;
    margin-left: 1px;
    width: 150px;
}
.rounded {
    border: 1px solid red;
    border-radius: 60px 0 0 0;
    font-size: 30px;
    height: 50px;
    left: 20px;
    line-height: 46px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 22px;
    font-size:30px;
}
</style>
<div class="circle">
</div>
<div class="rounded">blah blah blah blah blah blah</div>
```

Comment: Still not fitting the circle. :)

Answer (score 0):

Got it working, but with a trick.

Here is the answer:
http://jsfiddle.net/Beck/P63VY/64/

Thanks for trying though ppl.
64 updates lol :D

```
<div id="rounded1" class="rounded"></div>
<div class="circle">
    <div class="rounded"></div>
</div>
<div id="text">blah blah blah blah blah blah</div>

.circle {
    width:150px;
    height:150px;
    border-radius:82px;
    border:7px solid black;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.rounded {
    position: relative;
    top: 23px;
    left:-3px;
    background:red;
    width: 400px;
    height: 50px;
}
#rounded1 {
    position:absolute;
    top:38px;
    left:40px;
    background:red;
}
#text {
    position:absolute;
    top:38px;
    line-height:50px;
    padding-left:20px;
    font-size:30px; 
    color:white;
}
```